# require not defined when using sendGrid api

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, sendgrid

I keep getting a 'require not defined' error message when executing my code. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

```
    SENDGRID_API_KEY =
//   "api key here";

const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

const msg = {
  to: "test.account@gmail.com", // Change to your recipient
  from: "test2.account@gmail.com", // Change to your verified sender
  subject: "Sending with SendGrid is Fun",
  text: "and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js",
  html: "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>",
};

sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Email sent");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: which node version do you use?

Comment: Hey, I am using version 14.14.0

Comment: do you have the error on your local with `npm start`?

Comment: Hey, I get this error when running npm start: npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/tategraham/.npm/_logs/2020-11-09T02_03_02_011Z-debug.log

Comment: did you npm install?

Comment: Yes, I ran: npm install --save @sendgrid/mail

Comment: not sendgrid, did you npm install whole packages/

Comment: Hey, yes I have already done this

Comment: try to downgrade the node version, e.g. 12, remove node_modules and npm install again

Comment: Hey, this has not fixed the error